# Xamarin Profiler - Runtime installed on device Tablet in API 29 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Not able to connect Xamarin Profiler with Android Emulator. Error in log was ‘Runtime installed on device Tablet M-DPI 10.1in Q 10.0 in API 29 is too old. Deploy your app again with a newer version of Xamarin Studio’ ,

Checked in below versions,

1. Tablet M-DPI 10.1in Q 10.0 in API 29
2. Tablet M-DPI 10.1in Q 10.0 in API 30

Xamarin Profiler Version – 1.6.15.51
Visual Studio Enterprise Version – 16.10.2
SDK levels – 30,29,28

Comment: Can you try to connect your physical device?

Comment: In physical device also , I am facing same issue on android 11 samsung phone

Comment: Can not reproduce your problem, you can click **Help--Send feedback--Report a problem** to report this problem.